# Need help in understanding the reason for the use of the setRootPaneCheckingEnabled() method of the JFrame class

Tags: java, swing, jframe

This is more of a theoretical question. I was reading over the documentation of the JFrame class and it had a method called `setRootPaneCheckingEnabled()`, whose purpose seems to be controlling the forwarding of the `add()` and `setLayout()` calls to the JFrame's content pane. If we pass in true to this method, then the calls to `add()` and `setLayout()` are forwarded, and if we pass in false, these calls operate directly on the JFrame.

I'm not aware of a reason why someone would want the `add()` and `setLayout()` calls to operate on the JFrame directly and not it's content pane. Could someone please let me know about these reasons?

Comment: Ah, because you never coded in Java before 1.6.  In the "early" days, when dinosaurs walked the Earth and we coded on stone tablets with chisels, you would need to write `frame.getContentPane().add(...)`.  Seems simple enough, but do it often enough and it gets very, very tedious. Come along 1.6 and they add the ability to simply use `frame.add(...)` and have those calls forwarded to the `contentPane`.  This was also a great source of frustration to new coders, who didn't understand that  `JFrame` is actually a composite component and would waste hours trying to figure out why nothing worked

Comment: Also, back in the day, getting a decent IDE without complete was actually a difficult thing, so, yeah, typing that stuff out long hand was a complete pain in the ... wrists

Comment: Thanks a lot @MadProgrammer for letting me know about this! Do you mind adding this comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Btw @MadProgrammer, I just dug up some documentation based on your comment. It turns out that they started forwarding the calls to `add()` and `setLayout()` to the JFrame's content pane in Java 1.5. Before that you would have to add everything to the content pane manually. Here's the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/)

Comment: Ah, back in good old 1.5, those were the days, introduction of generics, sweet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before Java before 1.5, you would need to write `frame.getContentPane().add(...)`.

Seems simple enough, but do it often enough and it gets very, very tedious.

Come along 1.5 and they add the ability to simply use `frame.add(...)` and have those calls forwarded to the `contentPane`.

This might not seem like much, but it was probably one of the most highly questioned and asked for features in Swing, seriously.

This was also a great source of frustration to new coders, who didn't understand that `JFrame` is actually a composite component and would waste hours trying to figure out why nothing worked.

Also, back in the day, getting a decent IDE with auto complete was actually a difficult thing, so, yeah, typing that stuff out long hand was a complete pain in the ... wrists